# define a pointer to point to a class

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have this code for linked list implementation in C++: (just Node Class)

```
template <class, type>
    class node<type> {
        private:
            type data;
            node<type> *next;           
        };
```

and I've converted it to C#:

```
class Node<Type>
{
    internal Type data;
    internal Node<Type>* next;

    public Node(Type d)
    {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
};
```

in this line :

```
internal Node<Type>* next;
```

this error shows up :

```
cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type('Node<Type>')
```

what is the problem ? 
thanks a lot.

Comment: Just remove the "*". If you create a field of a reference type ("class ..."), this field is, well, already a reference. This corresponds to a pointer in C++.

Comment: this isn't necessary ? so I think i have to read pointers declaration in C# ?..

Comment: [Reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

Comment: Also, [Is there pointer in C# like C++? Is it safe?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2333574)